# Can't get my SQL to update the changes I passed through it

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

So I'm working on my project, I wanted to pass the changes through it and update two columns on a row.

I asked the user for their input

```
System.out.println("Which one of the reviews you would like to change?");
                List<Student> studentList = studentDao.getStudentRatings();
                for (Student students : studentList) {
                    System.out.println(students);
                }
                System.out.println("Enter your student ID");
                int student_idnumber = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();
                
                System.out.println("Enter your first name");
                String firstname = input.nextLine();
                
                System.out.println("Enter your last name");
                String lastname = input.nextLine();
                    
                System.out.println("Enter your new rating");
                int student_ratingnumber = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();
                
                System.out.println("Enter your new comments");
                String comment =  input.nextLine();
                
                
                
                studentDao.changeReview(student_idnumber, firstname,lastname, student_ratingnumber,comment);
```

then I pass these onto my studentDao

```
public void changeReview(int student_idnumber, String firstname, String lastname, int student_ratingnumber,
        String comment) {
    try(Connection connection = ConnectionUtil.getConnection()){
    String sqlString = "UPDATE student_things SET student_comments = ? , student_rating = ? where student_id = ?;";
    
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlString);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, student_idnumber);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, firstname);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, lastname);
    preparedStatement.setString(5, comment);
    preparedStatement.setInt(6, student_ratingnumber);
    
    
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    
    System.out.println("Review was updated");
}
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Change review failed");
    }
```

But then it fails every single time, as it would not update the table. I tried to run the same commands in postgres and the commands works, I tried to change the parameters for my preparedstatement. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  order of the parameters must match The order of The question marks. Especially shoild your student_id  be last.

Comment: So are you saying I should change `public void changeReview(int student_idnumber, String firstname, String lastname, int student_ratingnumber, String comment) ` to `public void changeReview(String comment, int student_ratingnumber, int student_id, String firstname, String lastname)`

Comment: No, you should change the order you add the values to the prepared statement. The numbers must match the order of the question marks in the SQL string.

Comment: You should add that by "order"  you mean the first argument to the `set*` methods.

Comment: Oh so it would be like,` preparedStatement.setInt(1, student_idnumber);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, firstname);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, lastname);
    preparedStatement.setString(5, comment);
    preparedStatement.setInt(6, student_ratingnumber);` to something like `
    preparedStatement.setString(4, comment);
    preparedStatement.setInt(5, student_ratingnumber);
    preparedStatement.setInt(6, student_id);`

Comment: The number in the first parameter  refers to the position if which question mark you watt to set, not the order of the column in the table.

Comment: Ah that was right, I was just confused on the wording, thanks for clearing it up.